Reincarnation manhua/manhwa/manga similar to "my secretly hot husband"
The story focuses on the female main character who I can't remember the name of who is a reincarnator from our world and is engaged to the prince at the beginning because she has the darkest blue hair and blackest eyes in the kingdom which means she is the most likely candidate to be the saint since the darkness of hair and eye color determines how much magical power you have and by that worlds standards how beautiful you are as well. Then one day the true saint with black hair and black eyes appears and since it's the prince's duty to marry the saint their engagement is broken off and then she is engaged to a border noble who is "colorless" and "ugly" by the world's standards. This isn't done out of spite though; it's done for the sake of the country since her magic would be crucial in order to strengthen the safety of the border from magic beast attacks which she had assisted in before. She is absolutely thrilled since although he's seen as ugly due to being colorless; he's absolutely gorgeous by our world's standards. Everyone of course views her having no problem with the arrangement as her putting up a strong front for the sake of both the country's future and sparing their feelings of guilt towards this necessary move.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Unfortunately, I don't remember any character names, but I read it 2-3 years ago.

by "colorless" do you mean that he had white, silver, or blonde hair? Or even an albino?

It was either platinum or white and his eyes were silver. I used "colorless" because I think it was a term that was used for him. Also I want to say that his rank was that of a count or lower.

Also there was a conversation about how if you found something other than hair and eye color attractive you were viewed as a pervert with a weird fetish like a previous emperor who insisted on seeing the ankles of his prospective brides.
